# Get the current cell in Excel VB

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small script in Excel/VB that I'm trying to get working.  All I want to do is select a dynamic range of data to copy but I can't seem to find any help/code on how to get the grid data (like A11).

Here is code I have from macro recording that selects the range of data:

```
Range("D291:D380").Select
```

I was hoping I could just do `Range(Current).Select` or something but that doesn't work.

How do I get the current cell using VBA?

Comment: App.ActiveCell ;)

Answer (score 36):

Have you tried:

For one cell:

```
ActiveCell.Select
```

For multiple selected cells:

```
Selection.Range
```

For example:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)
```

Comment: I think "ActiveCell.Address" will work.  I have a MsgBox that displays the variable data I'm trying to get.

Comment: @Apps I added a little more. Check it out.

Comment: To expand this answer, once you set `rng` you can then get `rng.Cells.Column` and `rng.Cells.Row`. To expand on `ActiveCell.Address`, if you `Dim s as String: s = ActiveCell.Address` it will return (for example) "$E$3".

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to grab a range with a dynamically generated string, then you just have to build the string like this:

```
Range(firstcol & firstrow & ":" & secondcol & secondrow).Select
```

Comment: App.ActiveCell.

Answer (score 2):

This may not help answer your question directly but is something I have found useful when trying to work with dynamic ranges that may help you out.

Suppose in your worksheet you have the numbers 100 to 108 in cells A1:C3:

```
          A    B    C  
1        100  101  102
2        103  104  105
3        106  107  108
```

Then to select all the cells you can use the `CurrentRegion` property:

```
Sub SelectRange()
Dim dynamicRange As Range

Set dynamicRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

End Sub
```

The advantage of this is that if you add new rows or columns to your block of numbers (e.g. 109, 110, 111) then the CurrentRegion will always reference the enlarged range (in this case A1:C4).

I have used CurrentRegion quite a bit in my VBA code and find it is most useful when working with dynmacially sized ranges. Also it avoids having to hard code ranges in your code.

As a final note, in my code you will see that I used A1 as the reference cell for CurrentRegion. It will also work no matter which cell you reference (try: replacing A1 with B2 for example). The reason is that CurrentRegion will select all contiguous cells based on the reference cell.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword "**Selection**" is already a vba Range object so you can use it directly, and you don't have to select cells to copy, for example you can be on Sheet1 and issue these commands:

```
ThisWorkbook.worksheets("sheet2").Range("namedRange_or_address").Copy
ThisWorkbook.worksheets("sheet1").Range("namedRange_or_address").Paste
```

If it is a multiple selection you should use the Area object in a for loop:

```
Dim a as Range
For Each a in ActiveSheet.Selection.Areas
    a.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").Paste
Next
```

Regards

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim app As Excel.Application = Nothing
Dim Active_Cell As Excel.Range = Nothing

Try
  app = CType(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
  Active_Cell = app.ActiveCell

Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox(ex.Message)
  Exit Sub
End Try

' .address will return the cell reference :)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this doesn't directly apply from the title of the question, However some ways to deal with a variable range could be to select the range each time the code runs -- especially if you are interested in a user-selected range. If you *are* interested in that option, you can use the Application.InputBox (official documentation page [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel)). One of the optional variables is 'type'. If the type is set equal to 8, the InputBox also has an excel-style range selection option. An example of how to use it in code would be:

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= "Please select a range", Type:=8)
```

**Note:**

If you assign the InputBox value to a none-range variable (without the `Set` keyword), instead of the ranges, the values from the ranges will be assigned, as in the code below (although selecting multiple ranges in this situation may require the values to be assigned to a variant):

```
Dim str as String
str = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= "Please select a range", Type:=8)
```